# cannot find module since the path is mentioned in the tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, protractor

My typescript code giving following error for paths which is specified in the tsconfig.json. please guide me to resolve this issue.

Error: Cannot find module 'flows/Maths'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)

[image: folder structure]

**src/flows/Maths.ts**

```
export class Maths {
    public add() {
        console.log('Add method')
    }
}
```

**src/specs/Start.ts**

```
import { Maths } from "@flows/Maths";
new Maths().add();
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
     "outDir": "./bin",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
     "baseUrl": "./src",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
     "paths": {
       "@flows/*":["flows/*"],
     },                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "relativepath",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node bin/specs/Start.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.12.11",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

do it like this:

```
 "paths": {
   "@flows/*":["./flows/*"],
 },
```

Need the "./" in front since you're using a base path.

and of course make sure you restart your project everytime you update tsconfig if you're not.

Comment: Also restarting VS Code helped me

Answer (score 3):

Your config should be

```
 "paths": {
   "@flows/*":["src/flows/*"],
 },
```

Normally tsconfig.json place outside of src folder so you need to add `src/` to your path also

Answer (score 0):

You should prefix the path with property name of in path array in tsconfig.

```js
// this should work.
import { Maths } from "@flows/Maths";
```

typescript compiler does not resolve the path but uses this configuration to resolve path for compilation. It is supposed to be used with module alias resolver such as

https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias

Comment: tried that also it showing the same error @Ranjeet Jain

Comment: @VenugopalP I don't see a tsconfig.spec.ts in your project structure. Is this being used then it is possible to override path it there. and also check your angular.json / .angular-cli.json which tsconfig file it is pointing to.

Comment: This is not for angular application development,  working for protractor typescript framework, in that i am facing this issue. Just i gave this code to explain my issue simply.

Comment: @VenugopalP updated the answer. You need to use other plugin to solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

@ mostly used for node module so might be conflicting try like this

```
"paths": {
       "~flows/*":["flows/*"],
        }
import { Maths } from "@flows/Maths";
```