# Cannot import newly added class

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Very strange issue. I have angular project (vs code as IDE). I add new file named `'log-logger'` with empty class `'LogLogger'`.

```
export class LogLogger{
    
}
```

I want to import this class in other file from other directory (but obviously the same project). So i made instance of this class in other:

```
import {LogLogger} from '@app/core/helpers/log-logger';
export MyOtherClass{
let x = new LogLogger();
}
```

What is funny - import has been added by "quick-fix" hint, but I still have error:

```
Cannot find module '@app/core/helpers/log-logger' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

Path is valid.

No difference between path `@app/core/...` and `../../helpers/log-logger`

WARNING: It's a minimal reproducible example. In my real project both classes are much more bigger, and class which I showed as LogLogger has constructor,many fields, and few methods.

Comment: Is `@app/core` declared in your tsconfig.json file? If it works with the direct path, but not with the path alias, try setting up your tsconfig.json like the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58976546/14956277).

Comment: Yes, '@app/core' is decalred in my tsconfig.json. Moreover - other imports in 'MyOtherClass' with '@app/core' works fine.

Comment: Interesting. The only other thing I'd check is that it's still broken after a new `ng build` and maybe restarting your IDE. I know the CLI *should* handle hot-reloading with new additions to a bundle, but it wouldn't shock me if there were edge cases that broke it.

Comment: @DM - I tried and... nothinh happen :/ I am still confused,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. **Remember that if you adding new file with new class add extension at the end of the name of file. In my case `log-logger.ts`** - IDE (VS Code) didn't show any error, class was properly colored and everything seemed to be fine.

Answer (score -2):

add class keyword

```
import {LogLogger} from '@app/core/helpers/log-logger';
export class MyOtherClass{
let x = new LogLogger();
}
```

Comment: Did you read my whole post? It's only minimal reproducible example where I provided scenario. "class" keyword is there... moreover even if not present, it won't cause my issue.
Regards